# Setting JAVA_HOME for portable eclipse

Tags: java, java-home

I am running Windows XP. I have a portable eclipse installed on a usb and when I tried installing the Android SDK it said "Java SE Development kit (JDK) not found" and told me to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable. The Java SDK is located in

K:\EclipsePortable\JDK\bin
K:\EclipsePortable\JRE\bin
K:\EclipsePortable\JDK\jre\bin
K:\EclipsePortable\App\Eclipse\JRE\bin

I am using K:\EclipsePortable\JDK\ so I assume I set it to one of those two paths. How do i do this? Is this in eclipse or a Windows thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An environment variable is for the operating system. As you are on Windows XP - follow these steps to set up a JAVA_HOME environment variable:

Click "Start" -> "Control Panel" and open "System". Choose "Advanced" tab and click on the "Environment Variables" button. In the "System Variables" section, add a new one named JAVA_HOME and put the value to your Java JDK directory (K:\EclipsePortable\JDK)

Alternatively you can press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> key combination which will bring up the "System Properties" window straight away, then you can go from there.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add a portable jdk with it, you need to tune up the eclipse.ini file. To do this add

```
-vm
K:\EclipsePortable\JDK\bin\javaw.exe
```

as shown below

```
  .
  .
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
K:\EclipsePortable\JDK\bin\javaw.exe
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
.
.
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  It's truly portable.