# What java installation folders can I get rid of?

Tags: java

My machine runs Windows 64 bits. I have multiple IDEs installed (eclipse, intelliJ, qt creator, visual studio) and I daily run some work applications that use java (vpn connector being the most important one).
Usually, when I get a java update notification I just accept and everything runs smoothly, but today I found that Eclipse is not starting because of exit error 13, which I read is caused by 32-bit/64-bit conflicts between Eclipse and Java. When I checked my java installation folders, I found out I have multiple folders, both for 32 bits and 64 bits:

I'm not even sure how those JRE folders ended up there, since I only download the JDK when I have to. Maybe they are the JRE installed with JDK but not sure.

Anyway, this is my 32-bit JAVA folder:
[image: 32 bits]

And this is my 64 bit-JAVA folder:
[image: 64 bits]

How can I get rid of all of those safely, download and install the latest JDK afresh and have everything running smoothly?

Thanks :)

Comment: You probably have the 32 bit JRE for some other application.

Answer (score 2):

The safest way remove Java installations on Windows is to run the respective uninstaller via the control panel.  In addition to deleting the installations themselves, the uninstaller will (should) remove related entries from the Windows registry.

As other answers note, you would still need to ensure that the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is updated to refer to the new Java installation, once you have installed it.

However, the problem with uninstalling copies of Java that you didn't explicitly install yourself is that you may end up breaking tools and applications that depend on those copies.  If the tools use `JAVA_HOME` you should be fine.  Otherwise, you might need to modify launcher scripts, etcetera.

If you are worried about this, you could *rename* the Java installations that you intend to remove, launch each of the apps, and see which of them breaks.  (Then rename the Java installations back ...)

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I just removed all of the older versions, leaving just the latest JDK for 64bit and the latest for 32bit. By running `java -version` in CMD I still found out that windows 7 was using 32bit as default (which, for example, was breaking eclipse startup) even though my JAVA_HOME was set to the 64bit. So I fixed it by adding the path to the 64bit version as the first thing in the PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem like this before (with a lot of version and JDKs installed).
The best way is just to delete everything and download it again, i know that it isn't the best solution and it will take some time to download and install everything again but it worked for me before.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter how many jdk/jre folders you have. Just make sure environment variable `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` points to the 64 bit jdk and jre folders correspondingly. You can remove other folders which are not pointed. The other applications may break after this change. You can fix them by pointing to this JAVA_HOME.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11237674/5678086) for setting JAVA_HOME env variable